What is the right abstraction to create an RPC mechanism between pyodide kernel running in a worker and jupyterlite running in the main thread?
I'm creating a Tampermonkey experimentation framework and I want to be able to call window.GM functions in the main thread from pyodide-kernel running in a worker. To reach this goal, I want to create an RPC mechanism between pyodide in the worker and the main thread using the comm layer built on top of postMessage by registering a new target.
I have prototyped this as a widget using AnyWidget but this seems like the wrong abstraction since it's not a visual widget that shows up in the notebook.  What is the right abstraction for this?  A server extension?  If so, what does the code look like that sets up the new comm target on the jupyterlite side?
